# Make systemd stop starting unwanted wpa_supplicant service?

Tags: systemd, configuration, services, wpa-supplicant

I wanted to disable `systemd` unwanted attempts to automatically start `wpa_supplicant`. I thougth I could simply run a

```
sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant.service --global
```

and I would not be seeing a wpa_supplicant in `ps -ef` output anymore. Anyway this did not work. 
How can I make it work?

My problem at hand might be best described by the output of

```
$>systemctl status wpa_supplicant*
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2016-08-28 20:57:37 CEST; 14min ago
```

where as you can see the `disabled` service is anyway loaded and active, thanks to systemd completely helping me do the simpletest thing ;)

**Update**
I seem to have had some luck by brutely removing these files:

```
wpa_supplicant-nl80211@.service
wpa_supplicant.service
wpa_supplicant@.service
wpa_supplicant-wired@.service
```

from `/usr/lib/systemd/system` folder. Guess what? After restart wpa is finally not started by `systemd` anymore. It strikes me though there must have been a more *peaceful* / *conciliatory* way to get `systemd` to have the service not being started.

Comment: Did masking the unit do nothing for you?

Comment: @KalvinLee I am not sure if what I did (removing the files) and masking (to my undestanding that would be keeping links named as those files which point to `/dev/null` is not essentually much of the same thing.) What you suggest is something I try. I must have not been looking enough in unix.se to see that `disbale vs mask systemd` question. I will try and state back soon, to update the question

Comment: Did disabling the template (wpa_supplicant@.service) help?

Comment: @maxf yes  (see that in the update I did remove also the template file) and that worked. I guess the real answer here was that what Kalvin Lee suggessted namely that really disabeling (not get it to start , even as a dependence or else, is to `mask` it). `systemctl mask` is the real disable (meaning the service is not there later on).

Comment: Uninstalling wpasupplicant would also work.

Answer (score 12):

The `sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant` + `sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant` will ONLY *temporarily disable* `wpa_supplicant` service until the network manager *restarts* and/or the system *reboots*.

So, to **correctly** and/or **completely** disable the `wpa_supplicant` service from running again in the future even after the network manager *restarts* and/or the system *reboots* is to **mask** the service, i.e.

```
systemctl mask wpa_supplicant.service
```

etc., as pointed out in this [article](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=51125#p250865). This will create a symbolic file

```
/etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service → /dev/null
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you AdminBee for the corrections and format and I really appreciated them.

Comment: *geoclue* / `geoclue.service` is an example for an application/service which can require to mask `wpa_supplicant`, as described in this answer. See https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geoclue/geoclue/-/issues/162

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue as yours. After some digging, I found a folder called:

```
/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service
```

This is file is used to allow the service to be activated by d-bus. d-bus can activate the service even if it is disabled. I confirmed that this was happening by re-naming the file, and then rebooting. I saw that at this point `wpa_supplicant` had not been started! To chase the issue down further would required finding out what program is activating `wpa_supplicant` via `d-bus`. I have not done this as masking the unit file works fine for my purposes.

Comment: Note that NetworkNanager requires  wpa_supplicant running ([url](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?259183-Does-NetworkManager-use-Wpa_Supplicant)). After I removed the file above, I lost access to wifi networks.

Answer (score 2):

All the previous answers are excessive. You can just disable NetworkManager's use of `wpa_supplicant` to manage wifi clients:

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

After this, NetworkManager won't try to manage wifi devices as clients.
Now you can just disable/stop the `wpa_supplicant` service without worrying that it will start automatically:

```
systemctl disable wpa_supplicant
systemctl stop wpa_supplicant
```

Note that NM might still be managing an active network interface for a wifi connection.
To kill this, just do `nmcli c` to view the interfaces, and then:

```
nmcli c d wlan0
```

... for a wifi interface named `wlan0`.

Comment: I am wondering if `nmcli c d wlan0` means `nmcli connection delete wlan0` or `nmcli connection down wlan0` ... I guess the `d` stands for `down`?

Comment: and `wlan0` is not a device, but rather the name of a connection, e.g. usually the SSID name?

Answer (score 1):

I tried following BrettB's suggestion, but it had no effect on my system.  (Ubuntu 18.04.)

However, the following did work:

```
sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really systemd that's being annoying here, it's NetworkManager.
You can tell NetworkManager to ignore wlan0.

There are some good ideas in this thread already.
I thought I'd add what I do to this list.

- @GChuf's method - Force NetworkManager to fail by deleting systemd files. Delete files so NetworkManager is shouting into the void. I'm not sure if this method would survive a package update.
- @Habibie's method - Force NetworkManager to fail by masking wpa_supplicant. This makes NetworkManager try a few times then give up.
- @ChalkTalk's method - Force NetworkManager to fail by turning off the radio. Looks like it runs systemd-rfkill.service.

### check the default setup

The default NetworkManager setup is to try to manage whatever it can get its hands on. NetworkManager runs wpa_supplicant to manage the WIFI interface wlan0. Here it is in the process list.

```
[nick@rpi4 ~]$ ps -fC wpa_supplicant
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         593       1  0 14:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -u -s
[nick@rpi4 ~]$
```

Wlan0 doesn't connect, and NetworkManager keeps trying.
Messages like these appear in the journal every few minutes.

```
[nick@rpi4 ~]$ journalctl -f

Mar 15 15:27:03 rpi4 NetworkManager[1526]: <info>  [1615822023.9272] device (wlan0): set-hw-addr: set MAC address to AA:9D:10:50:87:5B (scanning)
Mar 15 15:27:03 rpi4 NetworkManager[1526]: <info>  [1615822023.9359] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Mar 15 15:27:03 rpi4 NetworkManager[1526]: <info>  [1615822023.9362] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> interface_disabled
Mar 15 15:27:03 rpi4 NetworkManager[1526]: <info>  [1615822023.9367] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
Mar 15 15:27:03 rpi4 NetworkManager[1526]: <info>  [1615822023.9369] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: interface_disabled -> inactive
```

The status of wlan0 is *disconnected*.

```
[nick@rpi4 ~]$ nmcli device status
DEVICE         TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION               
wlan0          wifi      disconnected            --
```

### Tell NetworkManager that wlan0 is unmanaged

Edit the NetworkManager config and tell NetworkManager to ignore wlan0.

Stop the services.

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
systemctl stop wpa_supplicant
```

Add these lines to the bottom of the config file,  `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.
If you want a description of what *unmanaged-devices* is, run `man NetworkManager.conf`.

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:wlan0
```

Then run `systemctl start NetworkManager`.

Device state changes from *disconnected* to *unmanaged*.
The wpa_supplicant process doesn't start again, even though it's not masked.

```
[nick@rpi4 ~]$ nmcli device status
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION
wlan0       wifi      unmanaged               --   
...
[nick@rpi4 ~]$ ps -fC wpa_supplicant
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
[nick@rpi4 ~]$
```

Comment: Note that even if you're using `wlan0` as an AP or P2P and thus don't need a WPA supplicant, `NetworkManager` will still try to start it and fail if it cannot.