# Can't connect to networks wirelessly in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux

Newby here. I was struggling because I couldn't connect my laptop to a second WiFi Network, and I came to a post that said to me that was a problem of the wpa_supplicant service being working at the same time as the NetworkManager, so it was suggested to disable `wpa_supplicant.service`. I came to [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/614133) and disable it. But now I can't have internet on my other WiFi network, it only works via Ethernet.

The thing is, when I try to enable it again (once unmasked) `systemctl enable wpa_supplicant.service` it throws the following error:

`Failed to enable unit: Unit file wpa_supplicant.service does not exist.`

How should I recover this `wpa_supplicant.service` file?

Answer (score 1):

#### For your service file issue:

Sounds like you also followed his second advice and pointed the service file to `/dev/null`. If that is the case:

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service
```

and then try to enable/start it again and now it should work.

---

#### As for your network connection problem,:

First, the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306276/make-systemd-stop-starting-unwanted-wpa-supplicant-service/614133#614133) you referred to does not seem to be a solution to your problem.
You mentioned that,

> the wpa_supplicant service being working at the same time as the NetworkManager

And this is actually normal. As long as you have disabled `wpa_supplicant.service`, you should be good. `NetworkManager` would invoke `wpa_supplicant` on its own, and `wpa_supplicant` would eventually be running.

This is also why the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306276/make-systemd-stop-starting-unwanted-wpa-supplicant-service/614133#614133) you referred to said "(disabling the service) will ONLY temporarily disable `wpa_supplicant`". This behavior is actually desired since it allows `NetworkManager` to take control of your wireless network via `wpa_supplicant`. Disabling your own `wpa_supplicant.service` prevents your own service from conflicting with the one invoked by `NetworkManager`.

Then, to actually solve your connection issue... Are you trying to connect to two WiFi simultaneously? Or is it that your laptop connects to one wifi without any problem, but could not connect to the other? Also providing more details about your configuration and what you've tried would be helpful.